# Quotients of topological groupoids

Tags: groupoids, gn.general-topology

The issues that arise when moving from topological groups to topological groupoids are (at least to me) both subtle and interesting. Recently, I was reading a [paper](http://www.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/b-hardy1.pdf) of R. Brown and J.P.L. Hardy from 1974 which lists the following as an open problem:

**Problem:** Find a topological groupoid $G$ and a totally disconnected normal subgroupoid $N$ such that $G\rightarrow G/N$ (the map of morphism spaces) is not an open map.

Of course, this is not an issue with topological groups and normal subgroups.

Has this problem been settled? It has been a while and seems pretty accessible so I would imagine some progress has been made. If such $G$ and $N$ do exist, are there reasonable conditions we can place on them that do make $G\rightarrow G/N$ an open map?

I will make a couple of clarifications based on David's comment.

**Clarification:** Totally disconnected in this context is not topological. It means that $N(x,y)=\emptyset$ when $x\neq y$ so the components of $N$ (as a groupoid, not a space) are groups. R. Brown talks about these and quotient groupoids (but not topological groupoids) in "Topology and Groupoids."

As David points out, the problem refers to whether or not the morphism component of the canonical functor $G\rightarrow G/N$ is an open map of topological spaces.

Comment: What does totally disconnected mean in this context? Is it an algebraic condition or a topological condition? And the map G -> G/N, is this the arrow component of the canonical functor?

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd put my money on $\beta \omega$, equipped with its notion of 'addition' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Addition_on_the_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_naturals being somehow related to this.